# Change the text of the back button on Highcharts Treemap?

Tags: highcharts, treemap

I would like to change the text of the back / drill up button of my Highcharts Treemap. The button appears after the users click on the map to drill one level down.

By default, it shows "◁ Back" and I want to change it.

I have tried many different ways as shown below:

```
chart: {
  drilldown: {
    drillUpButton: {
      text: 'asdsad'
    }
  }
},

  Highcharts.setOptions({
lang: {
  thousandsSep: ',',
  drillUpText: 'asdasd',
  accessibility: {
    drillUpButton: 'terst'
  }
}})
```

Unfortunately, none of them works.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The treemap series doesn't use the `drilldown` module, it has implemented its own logic for `drilldown` and the drillup button text could be defined in the series config.

```
series: [{
  type: 'treemap',
  layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
  allowDrillToNode: true,
  drillUpButton: {
    text: '<< test button'
  },
  data: points
}],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nyjtufL7/

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't in the Highcharts API documentation.